# for different login id my perl environment variable and @INC have different values

Tags: perl

I find that for different login id my perl environment variable and @INC have different settings as below

sufuser (perl -V)

==========================

%ENV:

```
PERL5LIB="/opt/SMAW/SMAWsuf"
```

@INC:

```
/opt/SMAW/SMAWsuf
/opt/SMAW/SMAWrtppl/5.8.9-03/lib/perl5/5.8.9/x86_64-linux
/opt/SMAW/SMAWrtppl/5.8.9-03/lib/perl5/5.8.9
/opt/SMAW/SMAWrtppl/5.8.9-03/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.9/x86_64-linux
/opt/SMAW/SMAWrtppl/5.8.9-03/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.9
```

root (perl -V)

==========================

@INC:

```
/opt/SMAW/SMAWrtppl/5.8.9-03/lib/perl5/5.8.9/x86_64-linux
/opt/SMAW/SMAWrtppl/5.8.9-03/lib/perl5/5.8.9
/opt/SMAW/SMAWrtppl/5.8.9-03/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.9/x86_64-linux
/opt/SMAW/SMAWrtppl/5.8.9-03/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.9
```

how do i make them same for root users as in sufuser(persistent method is what i am trying to find)

First how to Set %ENV: for root in permanent way

Second Add  /opt/SMAW/SMAWsuf line to root user @INC section

Comment: system("export /opt/SMAW/SMAWsuf; push @INC, /opt/SMAW/SMAWsuf; perl -V ;/opt/SMAW/SMAWsuf/bin/displayPD -n Node03 >> /tmp/Details.txt");

I tried multiple wasy to set still no sucess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each user, you'll have to set the `PERL5LIB` environment variable. if you have control over the system, and everyone is using Bash shell, you should look at the `/etc/profile`file since this is executed first when a new user logs in. You shouldn't modify that file directly since it can be modified by an OS update. Instead look at it and see if there is some extension mechanism (for example, it sources in all files in the `/etc/profile.d` directory).

Even better, [create modules](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlnewmod.html) that get installed in your Perl distribution. It's fun and exciting!

Okay, it's not fun and exciting, but learning how to create good Perl modules and how to create unit tests for those modules will improve your Perl and increase portability. What if you're on a new machine? No problem because you can install those modules on a new machine. No need to modify PERL5LIB. No need to worry about side effects. You'll learn to write better code, and maybe learn a few things in the process that many Perl developers don't know, but should:

- [Namespace](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html) and the `package` command
- [Plain Old Doc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlpod.html) and the Perl [(`POD::Usage`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Pod/Usage.html) Module
- How [modules](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmodstyle.html) are structured.
- [Unit testing](http://perldoc.perl.org/Test.html) you code.

If you already know a lot of this information, then creating a module that can be installed in the default location shouldn't be difficult to do.

Yes, it takes more time, especially if you have to learn a lot of this, but doing something the right way takes much less time and effort in the end. If multiple users share the same modules on the same system, installing them correctly rather than hoping `$PERL5LIB` Is in sync between various users is the way to go.